# UPDATE/INSERT across three MySQL tables using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have 3 tables:

1. **`SMS_IN`** with 'raw' numbers (data is sent through SMS, so all numbers are in SMS form: I am 'exploding' them to get them into one number):

   ```
   sms_text
   sender_number
   sent_dt
   ```
2. **`members`** with members' mobile numbers:

   ```
   Memberid
   Username
   comp_id
   phone
   ```
3. **`mobile_numbers_test`** table of all their numbers:

   ```
   Memberid
   comp_id
   numbers
   contact_number
   active
   ```

I am trying to get `SMS_IN` (new numbers) into `mobile_numbers_test` (with old numbers), with 2 checks:

1. `SMS_IN.sender_number = members.phone`; and
2. If `SMS_IN.sender_number = mobile_numbers_test.contact_number AND SMS_IN.sms_text` (in explode form) `= mobile_numbers_test.numbers`, skip (or overwrite) - otherwise `INSERT`.

This is what I have so far:

```
include ('database_connection.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT phone FROM members")
or die(mysql_error());  
$no=0;
echo'<table>
        <tr>
        <td>Numbers</th>
        <td>From</th>
        <td>Date</th>
        </tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {$no++;
    $phone= $row['phone'];  
    $comp_id =  $row['comp_id'];
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM SMS_IN where sender_number ='$phone'")
    or die(mysql_error()); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
        {$no++;
        $sms= $row['sms_text'];
        $sms_no=$row['sender_number'];
        $sms_time=$row['sent_dt'];
        $sms_exp = explode("\r\n",$sms);
        foreach($sms_exp as $no )
        { //** not working from here **//

        $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members,mobile_numbers_test,SMS_IN 
        where members.phone = SMS_IN.sender_number and 
        mobile_numbers_test.numbers != '$no'
        ")
        or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
        {
        $circle=$row['state'];
        $price='Call Us';
        $contact_person=$row['Username'];
        $contact_number=$row['phone'];
        $type='Fancy';
        $per_post='Pre-Paid';
        $provider=$sms_exp[0];
        $date=strtotime($sms_time);
        $ip=$sms_no;
        $old_no=$row['numbers'];;

        if($old_no!=$no){ 
            echo '<tr><td>'.$no.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$contact_person.'</td></tr>';
        } else { echo 'Old No';
        }
        }
        }
        }

        }       
    echo'</table>';
```

In this example I `echo` the answer so that I know what's coming out... how do I `UPDATE` or `INSERT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a `UNIQUE` index in `mobile_numbers_test` on `(contact_number, numbers)` if one doesn't already exist:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE mobile_numbers_test ADD UNIQUE INDEX (contact_number, numbers);
   ```
2. Join `members` with `SMS_IN` on your join criterion:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM members JOIN SMS_IN ON SMS_IN.sender_number = members.phone
   ```
3. Loop over the resultset, exploding numbers and inserting into `mobile_numbers_test` using `INSERT IGNORE`.  Putting it all together (using PDO, because it'll make your life easier and you really ought to stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions: they are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ)):

   ```
   $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $user, $pass);

   $select = $dbh->query("
     SELECT * FROM members JOIN SMS_IN ON SMS_IN.sender_number = members.phone
   ") or die($dbh->errorInfo());

   $insert = $dbh->prepare("
     INSERT IGNORE INTO mobile_numbers_test
              ( Memberid,  comp_id,  numbers,  contact_number)
       VALUES (:Memberid, :comp_id, :numbers, :contact_number)
   ");

   while($sms = $select->fetch()) {
     foreach(explode("\r\n",$sms['sms_text']) as $no) $insert->execute(array(
       'Memberid'       => $sms['Memberid'],
       'comp_id'        => $sms['comp_id'],
       'numbers'        => $no,
       'contact_number' => $sms['sender_number']
     ));
   }
   ```

Comment: Thx man .. u made my day ... and yes i am new to mysql and php ... still learning ... so can u help in using PDO ... where can i learn any suggestion for good site or book ... thx ..great help

Comment: hi bro can we do 2 more check in this before entering data to mobile_numbers_test .?? 1st. i want to check if $no if 10 digit numeric or not (98765401324), and 2nd. if there are any (some Alphabet or symbol is there)  it should skip that value and enter next value .... is that possible